# How to change step by step the Memory heap size of android studio

Tags: android, memory

Hi guys i'm too much worrying of these problem in a long weekend, I haven't idea how to change the memory heap of android studio can anyone help me how to increase the memory heap?I need the step by step process,, i'm using windows 7 32 bit.Sorry guys but i cant post my image because my reputation is only

Comment: What are you hoping to achieve from this?

Comment: hi sir, At this moment i'm developing a huge project to display images and text but the android studio says "There's not enough memory to perform the requested operation, Please increase Xms setting" what should i do? i already visited some topics and i know how to set the xms but i didn't idea to find the JAVA_OPTIONS

Comment: I added your comment information to the Question, So you can remove your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you will do is, you will increase the JVM Heap.

To do that,
Go to your Environment Variables and see if you have a System Variable called `_JAVA_OPTIONS` with the value `-Xms256m -Xmx512m` (If you do not have it that is fine too), If you have it, change the value to `-Xms256m -Xmx1024m`, the max heap size will increased accordingly. If you do not have one add a Variable with Name `_JAVA_OPTIONS` with the value `-Xms256m -Xmx1024m`

Have a look at [this](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm) for the steps to create/update enviroment variables in OS.

EDIT:

Variable Name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
Variable Value: `-Xms256m -Xmx1024m`

[image]

Comment: No it is not in your IDE, it is your Operating system's environment variables.

Comment: sir i found it ! but i haven't environment variables name "java options", how to create that?  :))